# Extract value associated with column name on non-zero rows

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, categories

I have two dfs(500x100 & 1300x2) and want to create a new column in the first one with which categories that occur on each row. To achieve this I need to fetch the category associated with the column name from second df. There might be several categories on same row.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'apple': [0, 0, 1, 0], 
'strawberries': [0, 1, 1, 0], 
'cucumber': [1, 1, 0, 0], 
'hawthorn': [0, 1, 0, 1]
})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'storage': ['apple', 'strawberries', 'cucumber', 'hawthorn'],
'category': ['fruits', 'berries', 'vegetables', 'berries']
})
```

I've found two potential solutions which both aims to fetch value from dict when value of row is != 0:

```
df2_dict = dict(zip(df2['storage'], df2['category']))
df['categories'] = pd.Series(df.columns[np.where(df!=0)[1]]).map(df2_dict)
|
df['categories'] = df.apply(lambda s: ', '.join(s.index[s.eq(1)]), axis = 1).map(df2_dict)
```

These works to some extent but for some reason only give me results on about 1/10 of the rows. Desired output would be:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'apple': [0, 0, 1, 0], 
'strawberries': [0, 1, 1, 0], 
'cucumber': [1, 1, 0, 0], 
'hawthorn': [0, 1, 0, 1],
'categories': ['vegetables', 'berries, vegetables, berries',
'fruits, berries', 'berries' ]})
```

As of now column names are keys in dict. FYI the columns are dummies so only 0|1 in them.

Appreciate any smart solutions to this.
xoxo

Comment: Please update your constructor to be valid Python. You have two errors. First, the DataFrame is misspelt as `DateFrame`. Second, you can't enclose the dictionary `k: v` pairs in brackets.

Comment: plz check your code before asking

Comment: fixed the spelling, however the dict works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there might be easier ways of doing this but this works i think :)

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'apple': [0, 0, 1, 0], 
'strawberries': [0, 1, 1, 0], 
'cucumber': [1, 1, 0, 0], 
'hawthorn': [0, 1, 0, 1]})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'storage': ['apple', 'strawberries', 'cucumber', 'hawthorn'],
'category': ['fruits', 'berries', 'vegetables', 'berries']})

def cateogory (row):
    result = []
    for column in list(df.columns) :
        if row[column] == 1 :
            result.append (df2.loc[df2['storage'] == column]["category"])
    return [item for sublist in result for item in sublist]

df['category']  = df.apply(lambda row :  cateogory(row) , axis=1 )
```

Result :

```
   apple  strawberries  cucumber  hawthorn                        category
0      0             0         1         0                    [vegetables]
1      0             1         1         1  [berries, vegetables, berries]
2      1             1         0         0               [fruits, berries]
3      0             0         0         1                       [berries]
```

btw edited your example, there were some mistakes in it

Edit : corrected i think !

Comment: I think you misunderstood the goal. Your solution fetches the name of the column and not the category that the column name belongs to. There is also slightly too many columns to print it all out manually. I'd very much like an anonymous solution that loops over automatically.

Comment: make your desired output in example

Comment: oh yeah i see, how about now?

Comment: works like a charm!! Been struggling with this 2 days. Big thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
df.apply(lambda x:x.idxmax(), axis=1).map(dict(df2.values))
```

output:

```
0    vegetables
1       berries
2        fruits
3        greens
dtype: object
```

make result to `category` column

If there are `df` values ​​greater than 1, change `df`'s value to 0 or 1

```
df.gt(0).apply(lambda x:x.idxmax(), axis=1).map(dict(df2.values))
```

same result

If this is not result you want, draw desired output of the example.

**after edit question**

```
df.apply(lambda x: ','.join(x[x>0].index.map(dict(df2.values))), axis=1)
```

result:

```
0                   vegetables
1    berries,vegetables,greens
2               fruits,berries
3                       greens
dtype: object
```

make result to `category` column

Comment: Sorry for unclarity, think I clarified it now.

Comment: edit my answer after your editing